# Moving a Symony2 project from localhost to cPanel

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, cpanel

I have done my php project using Symfony2 framework. Now i nee to host it in a server with cPanel. The web folder in my server is public_html and my project web folder is named web. So if i copy the project and run commands like asset:install it wont work inside public_html. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to read this cookbook and follow instructions

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

be aware that this recipe is different for 2.0 or 2.1 and 2.2.